# Can't add options to db

Tags: theme-options, settings-api

I'm trying to create a really simple options page for my wordpress site that just contains one option - a conversion rate for a currency. I have the following code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'currency_options_set');
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_menu' );

function admin_menu () {
    add_options_page( 'Currency Options','Currency Options','manage_options','options_currency', 'settings_page' );
}

function currency_options_set(){
    register_setting( 'currency_options_group', 'currency_options' );
}

function  settings_page () {

    $default_options = array( 'currency_eur' => "1.1" );
    $options = get_option('currency_options', $default_options);
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php

        settings_fields("currency_options_group"); ?>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">EUR:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="currency_options_group[currency_eur]" size="40" value="<?php echo stripslashes($options["currency_eur"]); ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
        </p>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

The new options page shows and I can see the form but when I submit it, no options are saved to the wp_options table. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code, found an error in the input name. Change `currency_options_group` to `currency_options` will make it work. The modified code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'currency_options_set');
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_menu' );

function admin_menu () {
    add_options_page( 'Currency Options','Currency Options','manage_options','options_currency', 'settings_page' );
}

function currency_options_set(){
    register_setting( 'currency_options_group', 'currency_options' );
}

function  settings_page () {

    $default_options = array( 'currency_eur' => "1.1" );
    $options = get_option('currency_options', $default_options);
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php

        settings_fields("currency_options_group"); ?>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">EUR:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="currency_options[currency_eur]" size="40" value="<?php echo stripslashes($options["currency_eur"]); ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
        </p>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mixup in the `<input>` field of your options page.

In your case, the `name` of the input should be the name of the option you want to save, not an array of the `options_group`, as well as the output should be just the `option`, not an `$array` of the `options_group`.

The options would be like this:

```
$default_options = '1.1';
$options = get_option('currency_options', $default_options);
```

Your correct `<input>` would be this:

```
<input type="text" name="currency_options" size="40" value="<?php echo stripslashes($options); ?>" />
```

Wordpress automatically knows that currency_options is part of the currency_options_group (through `register_setting`), and you do not need to use it here.

The `options_group` is used in the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) for letting you automatically generate `wp-admin` settings pages by registering your settings and using a few callbacks to control the output.

One simple setting is easier and faster to do in your way.